# Generate multiple OR/AND statements

Tags: python, parsing, text

I am working on python script that splits text in different blocks based on keywords used in text.

Currently I split text into blocks with sth like this (for 1 block, others have pretty much the same strucure):

```
       if (line.strip().lower().startswith('ключевые навыки') 
        or line.strip().lower().startswith('дополнительная информация') 
        or line.strip().lower().startswith('знания') 
        or line.strip().lower().startswith('личные качества') 
        or line.strip().lower().startswith('профессиональные навыки')
        or line.strip().lower().startswith('навыки')):
```

But, it is possible that list of keywords is going to expand. Is there a possibility to generate multiple or statements based on some array of possible keywords?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say/do. But it looks like you should do `keywords = ['kno4eBble', 'Aononhnt', ...]` and then do `for keyword in keywords: if line.strip().lower().startswith(keyword):`. Or the above.

Comment: str.starts with accepts as input a tuple of items, e.g. `tup = ('a', 'b', 'c'); 'bar'.startswith(tup)`

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
values=['ключевые навыки','дополнительная информация','знания']
val=True
#enter any words you want to check
while val
    for i in values:
         if (line.strip().lower().startswith(i)):
              #whatever code you want to implement
              val=False
              #to exit loop
```

Hope it helps :)